# Cant hear duolingo

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, flash, alsa

On my desktop, I have headphones. Sites like facebook, and youtube play just fine, meaning audio works. I started duolingo on my laptop at home, with Ubuntu also. Where on my laptop it works fine. Here at work, on my Desktop, Duolingo doesn't work, or rather, I cant hear anything.  So I am confused. Why would other sites sound work, but not this one? I have adobe flash installed and enabled, and both browsers are Firefox 41.

From my account settings:
[image]

Just to show it is enabled. I also tried rebooting.

What can I try to get DuoLingo's audio to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Eventhough I don't know the cause of the problem, the solution offered on https://github.com/mikethedj4/duolingo-linux worked flawlessly for me over the last couple of weeks. It is a separate application that simply offers some kind of gateway to the Duolingo website. Installation instructions of the author can be found on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1m6ywCWkrgo. They are relatively simple, for Ubuntu standards at least.

Happy learning!